Help with query to get email volume information
I have 4 BUs in my SFMC org.
I created the following query with the intention of obtaining the total volume of emails sent per BU in a month, which is information already provided by Salesforce (Monthly summary of your Salesforce account).
Note that this query is filtered by the EventDate from the Sent table for the period of August/24:
Query:
SELECT
j.JobID,
j.EmailName,
COUNT(s.SubscriberKey) AS TotalEnvios
FROM
_Sent s
INNER JOIN
_Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
WHERE
s.EventDate BETWEEN '2024-08-01' AND '2024-08-31'
GROUP BY
j.JobID,
j.EmailName

The problem I’m encountering is that the final volume returned by this query, when summed up, does not match the volume presented by Salesforce in the Monthly summary of your Salesforce account, which was sent by my key account. I would like to know if this query is correct to obtain the information, and if it should match the report. If adjustments are needed, could you please guide me on how to modify the query to obtain the correct data?
Thanks in advance.

have you deleted any contacts? if so those sends would not be on _sent anymore

I would also recommend using intelligence reporting

@EazyE Yes, there are indeed contact purges in the org, but the discrepancy is actually in the report provided by the key account, not in the query itself. The query I’m running returns a higher volume than what is presented in the official Salesforce report.
